# Relationship between Python asyncio loop and executor

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I generally understand the concept of async vs threads/processes, I am just a bit confused when I am reading about the [event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html) of asyncio.

When you use `asyncio.run()` I presume it creates an event loop? Does this event loop use an executor? The link above says the event loop will use the default executor, which after a brief google search it appears to be `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

I am a bit confused if I am writing coroutines why would that use `ThreadPoolExecutor` since I don't want to execute my async code in threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When you use `asyncio.run()` I presume it creates an event loop?

Yes, from https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run:

> This function always creates a new event loop and closes it at the end.

---

> Does this event loop use an executor?

The event loop provides single-threaded concurrency for IO-bound work. For CPU-bound work, which would otherwise block the event loop, asyncio lets you execute code outside the event loop in a separate thread or process, by using an [*executor*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor).

This is done by calling [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor). It wraps the executor API and returns an *awaitable* which lets you use it transparently in `async`/`await` code, whereas if you used an executor directly, you would have to deal with [*futures*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) and callbacks.<sup>1</sup>

The event loop has a default executor which will be used by `run_in_executor` if no other executor is provided as argument. A custom default executor can be provided by calling [`set_default_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.set_default_executor).

If you don't call `run_in_executor` yourself, the code you pass to `asyncio.run` will not be executed in an executor, but asyncio might still use the default executor internally for some of its own code, I guess.

`asyncio.run` will automatically shut down the default executor at the end by calling [`shutdown_default_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.shutdown_default_executor) internally (since Python 3.9).<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> To illustrate the differences, suppose you want to do some CPU-intensive calculation in a separate thread and then report on the result.

Using `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `Future.add_done_callback`:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

def calculate():
    print("Calculating...")
    sleep(1)
    return 42

def report(future):
    print(f"The result is {future.result()}")

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future = executor.submit(calculate)
    future.add_done_callback(report)
```

Using `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `concurrent.futures.as_completed`:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import sleep

def calculate():
    print("Calculating...")
    sleep(1)
    return 42

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(calculate)]
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        print(f"The result is {future.result()}")
```

Using asyncio:

```
import asyncio
from time import sleep

def calculate():
    print("Calculating...")
    sleep(1)
    return 42

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, calculate)
    print(f"The result is {result}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

---

<sup>2</sup> I'm not sure if the remark about the change in Python 3.9 in https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run means that in earlier versions it did not shut down the executor at all, or if it did it by other means than calling `shutdown_default_executor`:

> This function runs the passed coroutine, taking care of managing [...], and closing the threadpool.
> [...]
> *Changed in version 3.9:* Updated to use `loop.shutdown_default_executor()`.

Comment: So if I have the most basic hello world coroutines and it won't be run inside an executor right? Can you please elaborate a bit more on "execute code outside the event loop"?

Comment: Like a real life example, the purpose of run_in_executor is still a bit vague to me, if I want to run my code in threads, why would I want to use async event loop? I could just use the normal multiprocessing api.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for trying to give some example, but like I said, if I want to use threads, I can use multiprocessing API https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html, what is the point of duplicating the feature in run_in_executor using ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: If you're already using asyncio you can use it without having to mix different APIs for concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mkrieger1's answer, my answer here is just to be a supplement to his/hers.

After reading a bit more about the `ThreadExecutor` vs `Multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`, it appears to me they are mostly similar with subtle differences, it's boiled down to personal choices.

To answer my own question why to have these 2 choices, my guess is that the `ThreadpoolExecutor` is for the asyncio domain, which can covert non-async compatible functions to execute "asynchronously" while retaining the asyncio syntax, I suspect the Django `sync_to_async` utilises this?